# python Django Field 'id' expected a number but got '{"isTrusted":true}'

Tags: python, django

mistake：

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got '{"isTrusted":true}'
```

When I attempt to perform the delete operation, an error is being reported, and I'm unsure how to resolve it.

view.py

```
class ClassAdminAPI(APIView):
    @validate_serializer(CreateClassSeriaizer)
    @super_admin_required  
    def post(self, request):
        class_data = request.data
        class_data["title"] = class_data.get("title")
        class_data["start_time"] = dateutil.parser.parse(class_data["start_time"])
        class_data["end_time"] = dateutil.parser.parse(class_data["end_time"])
        class_data["created_by"] = request.user

        if class_data["end_time"] <= class_data["start_time"]:
            return self.error("Start time must occur earlier than end time")

        user_data = class_data.pop("users") 

        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                if Class.objects.filter(title=class_data["title"]).exists():
                    return self.error("Class with the same title already exists")

                class_obj = Class.objects.create(**class_data)  
                for data in user_data:
                    if len(data) != 4 or len(data[1]) > 32:
                        return self.error(f"Error occurred while processing data '{data}'")

                    username = data[1] + data[2]

                    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, defaults={
                        "password": make_password(data[1]),
                        "college": data[3],
                        "student_number": data[1]
                    })

                    if created:
                        profile = UserProfile(user=user, real_name=data[2])
                        profile.save()

                    class_obj.users.add(user)

            return self.success(ClassSerializer(class_obj).data)

        except IntegrityError as e:
            return self.error(str(e).split("\n")[1])

@super_admin_required
    def get(self, request):
        class_id = request.GET.get("id")

        if class_id:
            try:
                class_obj = Class.objects.get(id=class_id)
                ensure_created_by(class_obj, request.user)
                return self.success(ClassSerializer(class_obj).data)
            except Class.DoesNotExist:
                return self.error("Class does not exist")

        classes_obj = Class.objects.all().order_by("-create_time")
        # print("classes_obj:", classes_obj)
        if request.user.is_admin():
            classes_obj = classes_obj.filter(created__by=request.user)
            print("classes_obj:", classes_obj)
        return self.success(self.paginate_data(request, classes_obj, ClassSerializer))

 @super_admin_required
    def delete(self, request):
        Class_id = request.GET.get("id")
        if not Class_id:
            return self.error("Invalid Parameter, id is required")
        class_ids = Class_id.split(",")
        if Class.objects.filter(id__in=class_ids, created_by=request.user).exists():
            return self.error("Current class cannot be deleted")
        Class.objects.filter(id__in=class_ids).delete()
        return self.success()
```

serializers.py

```
class CreateClassSeriaizer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=False)
    start_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    end_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    users = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length=64)), required=False)

class ClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UsernameSerializer()
    status = serializers.CharField()
    # title = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    # start_time = serializers.DateTimeField()
    # end_time = serializers.DateTimeField()
    # users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = "__all__"

class EditClassSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=False)
    start_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
    end_time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
```

models.py

```
class ClassStatus:
    CLASS_NOT_START = "1"
    CLASS_ENDED = "-1"
    CLASS_UNDERWAY = "0"



class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()

    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='created_classes')

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='enrolled_classes')


    @property
    def status(self):
        if self.start_time > now():
            return ClassStatus.CLASS_NOT_START
        elif self.end_time < now():
            return ClassStatus.CLASS_ENDED
        else:
            return ClassStatus.CLASS_UNDERWAY

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Class"
        ordering = ("-start_time",)
```

I tried printing the Class_id, and the content was isTrusted:true. I don't understand why it is like that.I don't even know where isTrusted is coming from.

Revised version:Sorry, this is my first time writing this, and I'm not sure if "GET request" refers to this：

```
getClassList (page) {
        this.loading = true
        api.getClassList((page - 1) * this.pageSize, this.pageSize).then(res => {
          this.loading = false
          this.total = res.data.data.total
          this.ClassList = res.data.data.results
          // console.log(this.ClassList)
        }, res => {
          this.loading = false
        })
      },

      deleteClass (Classid) {
        this.$confirm('Sure to delete this class? ', 'Delete Class', {
          type: 'warning'
        }).then(() => {
          api.deleteClass(Classid).then(() => {
            this.getClassList(this.currentPage)
          }).catch(() => {
            this.getClassList(this.currentPage)
          })
        }, () => {
        })
      },
```

And api.js

```
  deleteClass (id) {
    return ajax('admin/Class', 'delete', {
      params: {
        id
      }
    })
  },
getClassList (offset, limit, keyword) {
    let params = {paging: true, offset, limit}
    if (keyword) {
      params.keyword = keyword
    }
    return ajax('admin/Class', 'get', {
      params: params
    })
  }
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/OnlineJudge/utils/api/api.py", line 149, in dispatch
    return super(APIView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/OnlineJudge/account/decorators.py", line 28, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/OnlineJudge/Class/views/admin.py", line 112, in delete
    if Class.objects.filter(id__in=class_ids, created_by=request.user).exists():
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1415, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1347, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1193, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 240, in get_prep_lookup
    rhs_value = self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(rhs_value)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/oj/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1827, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got '{"isTrusted":true}'.
```

Comment: how you sending request to the view?

Comment: Please share your GET request

Comment: `{"isTrusted":true}` is due to user is not `authenticated`. try login again and do the request

Comment: Share the full tracekback.

Comment: Traceback and GET request added. Thanks and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out where my problem was.
This is my previous code for the delete button in Vue：

```
<icon-btn name="Delete" icon="trash" @click.native="deleteClass"></icon-btn>
```

And this is the updated version:

```
<icon-btn name="Delete" icon="trash" @click.native="deleteClass(scope.row.id)"></icon-btn>
```

Thank you very much to everyone who responded to my questions earlier. I really appreciate it!